# How do you install rbash in CentOS 7?

Tags: bash, centos, software-installation, yum, restricted-shell

I ran this command:

```
yum install rbash
```

And for some reason it told me that the package wasn't available. It didn't come pre-installed on my system either and when I looked it up I was unable to find anyone else having this issue. So how do you install rbash on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rbash is just bash invoked with the `-r` or `--restricted` option.  All you have to do is link bash to rbash:

```
ln /bin/bash /bin/rbash
```

When invoked as rbash, bash will automatically act as restricted.

Comment: This worked, thanks. Will accept when I can.